# How to change Product Listing Sort by custom select option?

Tags: magento2, plugin, sort

In my module, I have created a select option with attributes. When I select an attribute, that attribute will be set to sort by default. How can I do that. I found

> Magento\Catalogfile\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar.php

[image]

but I do not know how to use the plugin to change that default value.
Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: @ChiragPatel 
What plugin should I use in that file?